# Creating a View that is a UNION of a few tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

A client of mine would like to create a view that is a `UNION` of a few tables.

From the client:

> These tables are populated by streaming data sources and are pretty
>   sizable already. Because of how the set operations get applied, any
>   queries of this view are causing performance issues, since any
>   filters/predicates get applied after the `UNION`s. I know that you
>   can’t materialize a view with `UNION` operations, so I was wondering
>   if Snowflake recommends any other solution short of building a
>   separate table which unions the constituent tables.

Comment: The answer could depend drastically on the details of your data. Generally: I'd recommend looking at the query profile to see if you can find ways to allow your query to do more pruning.  https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/ui-query-profile.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a view as follows and pruning worked as expected, prior to the UNION.

I wonder if their problem is due to `UNION` (has the performance penalty of de-duping) versus `UNION ALL`

```
create or replace view test_unions
(
  mycol1,
  mycol2,
  mycol3
) as (
  (select mycol1,mycol2,mycol3 from tableA)
  union all (select  mycol1,mycol2,mycol3 from tableB)
  union all (select  mycol1,mycol2,mycol3 from tableC)
)
;
```

[image: query plan]